# Javascript: как получить все координаты повернутого прямоугольника?

Tags: javascript, математика, координаты

Есть два прямоугольника произвольного размера. Прямоугольники **могут быть произвольно повернуты**. Прямоугольникам заданы координаты.

Задача определить пересекаются ли прямоугольники(в любой хотя бы 1 точке). Именно контур прямоугольников, не контур поворота(который можно получить через getboundingclientrect). Ниже 2 картинки, 1 - нет пересечения, 2 - есть пересечение.

[image: не пересекаются]

[image: пересекаются]

Вот найденное решение задачи:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3qhfLnj/2/

Но, в данном решении координаты прямоугольников считаются при помощи созданных дополнительных внутренних элементов с абсолютным позиционированием.

```
<div id="a">
        <div class="left-top" rel="yellow"></div>
        <div class="right-top" rel="red"></div>
        <div class="right-bottom" rel="blue"></div>
        <div class="left-bottom" rel="lime"></div>
    </div>
```

Вопрос: как можно получить все 4 точные координаты **повернутого прямоугольника** другим способом без использования этих костылей?

или может есть другое решение первой задачи?

Прямоугольников много, считаться будет всё на лету. Поэтому вариант добавлять в каждый прямоугольник "4 уголка" не подходит.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99124/discussion-on-question-by-floyat-javascript-----).

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки пересечения повернутых прямоугольников можно использовать метод разделяющих осей ([Separating Axes Theorem](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf) c кодом на C++). Хотя метод более общий (работает для любых выпуклых многоугольников), в применении к прямоугольникам он вполне хорош

[Вот здесь есть некий код](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169) на AS3, если это легче перевести на JS (New Implementation)

```
//results of P, Q
var result_P1:Object = getMinMax(vecs_box1, normals_box1[1]);
var result_P2:Object = getMinMax(vecs_box2, normals_box1[1]);
var result_Q1:Object = getMinMax(vecs_box1, normals_box1[0]);
var result_Q2:Object = getMinMax(vecs_box2, normals_box1[0]);

//results of R, S
var result_R1:Object = getMinMax(vecs_box1, normals_box2[1]);
var result_R2:Object = getMinMax(vecs_box2, normals_box2[1]);
var result_S1:Object = getMinMax(vecs_box1, normals_box2[0]);
var result_S2:Object = getMinMax(vecs_box2, normals_box2[0]);

var separate_P:Boolean = result_P1.max_proj < result_P2.min_proj || 
                         result_P2.max_proj < result_P1.min_proj
var separate_Q:Boolean = result_Q1.max_proj < result_Q2.min_proj || 
                         result_Q2.max_proj < result_Q1.min_proj
var separate_R:Boolean = result_R1.max_proj < result_R2.min_proj || 
                         result_R2.max_proj < result_R1.min_proj
var separate_S:Boolean = result_S1.max_proj < result_S2.min_proj || 
                         result_S2.max_proj < result_S1.min_proj


//var isSeparated:Boolean = separate_p || separate_Q || separate_R || separate_S
if (isSeparated) t.text = "Separated boxes"
else t.text = "Collided boxes."
```